# Custom curved lines in Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, shader, bezier

I am working on a game where I have some bezier curves. At the moment, everything is fine and it's working as it should, although I do some complicated operation on this curves. To draw the curves I use a canvas and paths, like this:

```
private void refresh() {
    mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(start_x, start_y);
    mPath.cubicTo(anchor1_x, anchor1_y, anchor2_x, anchor2_y, end_x, end_y);
}
public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {
    Path newPath = new Path(mPath);
    Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    mMatrix.setTranslate(-mCamera.x1, -.mCamera.y1);
    mMatrix.postScale(mCamera.getWidthRatio(), mCamera.getHeightRatio());
    newPath.transform(mMatrix);
    canvas.drawPath(newPath, paint);
}
```

The paint parameter is ussually the following one:

```
 curvesPaint = new Paint();
 curvesPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
 curvesPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
 curvesPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
 curvesPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
 curvesPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
 curvesPaint.setStrokeWidth(canvas.getHeight() / 100f);
 if (shadow)
      curvesPaint.setShadowLayer(canvas.getHeight() / 50f, 0, 0, 0xAAFFFFFF);
 else
     curvesPaint.setShadowLayer(0, 0, 0, 0xAAFFFFFF);
```

My question is: how can I make the curves more beautiful? At the moment, they're only white (or white with a white shadow). I want to be able to draw them with a nice gradient or model on them and I have no idea how to do that. I was thinking about the setShader function of the Paint class but I don't know if I can use it for my purpose or how to use it. Other solutions, like drawing multiple paths one above the other, is clearly impractical due to low fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start looking at using OpenGL or third-party wrapper libraries such as libgdx. `Canvas` is meant for relatively simple graphics. I don't think it takes advantage of the devices GPU. To take advantage of the full power of the GPU, you will need to use OpenGL.